# ArcGIS JS 4.15 Cluster Popup navigation for Cluster

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, clustering, popup, spatial-cluster

I would like to migrate from ArcGIS JS API 3.x to 4.16. One other feature I am using from 3.x version is clustering. In 3.x is it allow user to click on [Cluster marker](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/samples/layers_point_clustering/) and navigate between all individual marker information in inforwindow.

I am not able to replicate same behavior 4.15. I would like to know if it is possible rather than showing summary popup.

What I am looking for is to get list of features on click on a cluster, which was possible in 3.x but I am unable to figure it out in 4.16

Comment: the popup contains a navigation of the features that integrate the cluster, is not that what you are looking for?

Comment: @cabesuon Yes .I want navigation feature. in 4.15 cluster by default it provide a summarized information of cluster. which I do not want. I want something like 3.x which allows to navigate all feature in a cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by [ArcGIS Dev on Forum](https://community.esri.com/message/946689-re-when-does-point-clustering-come?commentID=946689&et=watches.email.thread#comment-946689), as of 4.16 Cluster do not support to `getChildGraphics` of cluster and also do not support different renderer for cluster.